# How to implement Debug trait for runtime GenesisConfig?

Tags: genesis

[GenesisConfig](https://docs.substrate.io/build/genesis-configuration/) is implemented for each pallet, but the runtime `GenesisConfig` (ex: `polkadot::GenesisConfig`) is not implemented explicitly. So my question is: how to implement a trait (`Debug` for example) for the generated runtime genesis config? Since trait implementation have to go along struct definition, where should this implementation go?

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to accomplish that. Can you tell me more about your specific use case?

Comment: The use case is to debug a strange problem where grandpa finalization does happen or not depending on the genesis config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the pallet `GenesisConfig` nor the aggregated `GenesisConfig` implement `Debug`.
A change to FRAME would be needed to also expand this derive ([#13955](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13955)). Could definitely be done, but could break some existing downstream code that has non-`Debug` fields in their Configs.

You can additionally implement stuff on the `GenesisConfig` in the same module as the `construct_runtime!` - *should* work. So that could also work for `Debug` (did not try).

Anyway, you can also use `serde_json` to encode and "print" it.
For example the Polkadot testnet config (minus WASM blob) looks like this:

```
{
  "system": {
    "code": "0x"
  },
  "babe": {
    "authorities": [],
    "epochConfig": {
      "c": [
        1,
        4
      ],
      "allowed_slots": "PrimaryAndSecondaryVRFSlots"
    }
  },
  "indices": {
    "indices": []
  },
  "balances": {
    "balances": []
  },
  "staking": {
    "validatorCount": 50,
    "minimumValidatorCount": 4,
    "invulnerables": [],
    "forceEra": "ForceNone",
    "slashRewardFraction": 100000000,
    "canceledPayout": 0,
    "stakers": [],
    "minNominatorBond": 0,
    "minValidatorBond": 0,
    "maxValidatorCount": null,
    "maxNominatorCount": null
  },
  "session": {
    "keys": []
  },
  "grandpa": {
    "authorities": []
  },
  "imOnline": {
    "keys": []
  },
  "authorityDiscovery": {
    "keys": []
  },
  "democracy": {
    "phantom": null
  },
  "council": {
    "phantom": null,
    "members": []
  },
  "technicalCommittee": {
    "phantom": null,
    "members": []
  },
  "phragmenElection": {
    "members": []
  },
  "technicalMembership": {
    "members": [],
    "phantom": null
  },
  "treasury": null,
  "claims": {
    "claims": [],
    "vesting": []
  },
  "vesting": {
    "vesting": []
  },
  "nominationPools": {
    "minJoinBond": 0,
    "minCreateBond": 0,
    "maxPools": 16,
    "maxMembersPerPool": 32,
    "maxMembers": 512,
    "globalMaxCommission": null
  },
  "configuration": {
    "config": {
      "max_code_size": 10485760,
      "max_head_data_size": 32768,
      "max_upward_queue_count": 8,
      "max_upward_queue_size": 1048576,
      "max_upward_message_size": 51200,
      "max_upward_message_num_per_candidate": 5,
      "hrmp_max_message_num_per_candidate": 5,
      "validation_upgrade_cooldown": 2,
      "validation_upgrade_delay": 2,
      "async_backing_params": {
        "max_candidate_depth": 0,
        "allowed_ancestry_len": 0
      },
      "max_pov_size": 5242880,
      "max_downward_message_size": 1048576,
      "hrmp_max_parachain_outbound_channels": 4,
      "hrmp_max_parathread_outbound_channels": 4,
      "hrmp_sender_deposit": 0,
      "hrmp_recipient_deposit": 0,
      "hrmp_channel_max_capacity": 8,
      "hrmp_channel_max_total_size": 8192,
      "hrmp_max_parachain_inbound_channels": 4,
      "hrmp_max_parathread_inbound_channels": 4,
      "hrmp_channel_max_message_size": 1048576,
      "executor_params": [],
      "code_retention_period": 1200,
      "parathread_cores": 0,
      "parathread_retries": 0,
      "group_rotation_frequency": 20,
      "chain_availability_period": 4,
      "thread_availability_period": 4,
      "scheduling_lookahead": 0,
      "max_validators_per_core": null,
      "max_validators": null,
      "dispute_period": 6,
      "dispute_post_conclusion_acceptance_period": 100,
      "no_show_slots": 2,
      "n_delay_tranches": 25,
      "zeroth_delay_tranche_width": 0,
      "needed_approvals": 2,
      "relay_vrf_modulo_samples": 2,
      "pvf_checking_enabled": false,
      "pvf_voting_ttl": 2,
      "minimum_validation_upgrade_delay": 5
    }
  },
  "paras": {
    "paras": []
  },
  "hrmp": {
    "preopenHrmpChannels": []
  },
  "xcmPallet": {
    "safeXcmVersion": 3
  }
}
```

Concretely, extending the `GenesisConfig` for Polkadot can be done like this. Note that it is only available in `std`:

```rust
#[test]
fn extend_genesis() {
    impl core::fmt::Debug for GenesisConfig {
        fn fmt(&self, writer: &mut core::fmt::Formatter) -> core::fmt::Result {
            write!(writer, "{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(self).unwrap())
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", GenesisConfig::default());
}
```

Comment: I tried to add
```impl core::fmt::Debug for GenesisConfig {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut core::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> core::fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("GenesisConfig").finish()
    }
}
```
after my `construct_runtime!` macro, but `GenesisConfig` is not found in scope. That was the sense of my question: "where" means : "which scope".

Comment: For the `serde_json` approach, it would be good if `GenesisConfig` were implementing `Clone` trait, which is not the case. Difficult to implement without, but I'll try :/

Comment: The genesis config only exists in `std`. So you have to guard your impl for `std` or put it inside a test. (I updated the answer).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it answers the question, but now I'm stuck with deriving `Clone` trait 

Comment: Agreed; it should be `Clone`. I will change it. In the mean-time you can again use `serde_json` to encode+decode to "clone" it , since encode only requires a reference (obviously a horrible hack).